# How to increment filename if it exists?

Tags: powershell

I would like to produce reports of security groups which the user is memberof. How I could increment the file if it already exists by a digit at the end? I'm not familiar with this, I'll appreciate your help

```
$Users = @"
SamAccountName;
FloydS
AdamS
SvacouM
FloydS
"@ | Convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ";"

$FilePath = "C:\TEMP\"
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd

Foreach ($User in $Users) {

(Get-ADUser $User.SamAccountName –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Export-excel -Path "$FilePath$((get-aduser $User.SamAccountName -Properties Name | select name).name) ($(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")).xlsx" -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2

 }

 Write-Host "Done!"
```

Comment: Why not just add a more specific timestamp? eg. `Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"`

Comment: Just use a plus sign to add a number to a string  : $baseFilename = "abc"; $newfilename = "abc" + 1 + ".txt"  Notice one is not in double quotes.  PS will automatically change the number to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will create filenames with index number between brackets (like Windows would do) if a filename already exists.

I also changed your code where you did an extra `Get-ADUser` call where you already had that info

```
$Users    = 'FloydS','AdamS','SvacouM'
$FilePath = 'C:\TEMP'
$today    = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $adUser   = Get-ADUser $User –Properties MemberOf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adUser) {
        $adGroups = $aduser.MemberOf | ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name }
        # create the filename without extension combining the user name and current date
        $outBaseName = '{0} {1}' -f $adUser.Name, $today  
        # combine that into the full path and filename
        $outFullName  = Join-Path -Path $FilePath -ChildPath ('{0}.xlsx' -f $outBaseName)
        # loop while that filename already exists and add an index number until unique
        $index = 1
        while (Test-Path -Path $outFullName -PathType Leaf) {
            $outFullName  = Join-Path -Path $FilePath -ChildPath ('{0}({1}).xlsx' -f $outBaseName, $index++)
        }
        $adGroups | Export-Excel -Path $outFullName -WorksheetName $today -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find user '$User'.."
    }
}

Write-Host "Done!"
```